# Dynamically align an UITextView inside a TableView Row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alignment

The idea is to do something like WhatsApp that aligns the messages on left/right for each user.

I'm trying this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("messageCell") as! MessageCell

    // get the items in this section
    let sectionItems = self.getSectionItems(indexPath.section)

    // get the item for the row in this section
    let currentMessage = sectionItems[indexPath.row]

    var messageTextViewAlignment: NSLayoutFormatOptions

    if (currentMessage.from == self.currentUserId)
    {
        messageTextViewAlignment = NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllRight
    }
    else
    {
        messageTextViewAlignment = NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeft
    }

    var newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[messageTextView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["messageTextView": cell.messageTextView])

    cell.messageTextView.addConstraints(newConstraint)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: im tried this too, but didnt works:

cell.messageTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin

cell.messageTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin

Comment: I don't see where you assign `messageTextViewAlignment` to the cell?

Comment: in field options, i tried but didn't work too...

Comment: In field options you are using  `NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX`?

Comment: i change in the code for test only, but didn't stay center every way...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve. Align the UILabel on the correct side of the screen or align the text within the `UILabel`

Imagining you want to align the `UIlabel`to have this cool empty space left or right from the bubble like in What's App. here some thing you could try :

## Using IB

Since you are using IB for a custom UITableViewCell that seems only to contain the message, could not just have `IBOutlets` for you leading ans trailing constraints from the `UILabel` to the cell `contentView` margins.

It would look like :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelLeadingConstrain;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelTrailingConstrain;
```

And in your code

```
if (currentMessage.from == self.currentUserId)
{
    labelLeadingConstrain = X1;
    labelTrailingConstrain = X2;
}
else
{
    labelLeadingConstrain = X2;
    labelTrailingConstrain = X1;
}

[...]

return cell
```

}

## Programmatically

I am less familiar with constraints handled this way but try

```
if (currentMessage.from == self.currentUserId)
{
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-X1-[constraintUILabel]-X2-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"constraintUILabel" :cell.messageTextView}]];
}
else
{
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-X2-[constraintUILabel]-X1-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"constraintUILabel" :cell.messageTextView}]];
}

[...]

return cell
```

}

## Using AlignAllRight

This constraint applies to 2 views at least. So there is your `messageTextView` and assume you have a `messageView`which contains it (may be the tableViewCell' contentView itself)

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[messageTextView][messageView]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight metrics:nil views:@{@"messageTextView" :cell.messageTextView},@"messageView" :cell.messageView}]
```

In your snippet the `messageTextViewAlignment`variable is never used so I believe you should use the snipped above (Swift styled) replacing `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight`with your `messageTextViewAlignment`var

Comment: before i ask here, i did with constraints, it works, but i think is not a goo solution

Comment: OK, in that case I do not get why you are applying your constraint onlt-y to `messageTextViewAlignment`. The `AlignAllRight`aligns the right edges of  several views so I believe you need at least 2 views in your input. I will edit my response since  to propose an option

Answer (score 0):

@"NiColas Braun" Before ask here, i code this solution, something like you suggest in "Using IB", it works, but i think is not a good solution:

```
func alignTextView(textViewAlignment: NSLayoutFormatOptions)
{
    horizontalSpaceFromContentViewToTextView.constant = 0

    let spaceX = initialTextViewWidth - finalTextViewWidth

    if( spaceX > 0 )
    {
        if (textViewAlignment == NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllRight)
        {
            horizontalSpaceFromContentViewToTextView.constant = spaceX
        }
    }
    //println("spcaceX: \(spaceX) --- \(messageTextView.text)")
}
```

I want to do work with NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllRight and NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeft